# Spring Boot Deploying Old Project

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I had created a spring boot project in the past, and now I am coming back to using spring boot again.  However, I am running into issues when I click "run as spring project" (which informs me that my server/app has deployed as expected on port 8080 with a context root of "/").  When I open my browser and go to localhost:8080, it still shows up with content from my old project.  Any ideas on how to fix this? (P.S. it is not a maven issue -- I have clean/installed).

Answer (score 0):

Try following these steps :
1)Stop all the Java processes in your system .
2) Restart your app .
3) Open a new incognito window in your browser and try again .

If it still doesnt work , provide more details like which version of Spring boot are you using and contents of your application.properties .
Also , are you using docker to run your apps?

Comment: hi, thank you for your insights.  I have killed all java/javaw processes on my system and restarted my app, and even my computer, however, none of this works.  My application.properties is as follows (password changed for safety reasons)

cloud.aws.region.static=us-east-2
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://gvsubooksellback.ceio3kwcmhrj.us-east-2.rds.amazonaws.com
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=********

As for my spring boot version, my pom.xml suggests that I am running version: 2.0.1.RELEASE.

Any other ideas on what could be wrong?

Comment: try changing the context root of your project . If you are using spring boot 2 , the propertyto add in application.properties is : server.servlet.context-path=/yourcontextpath

Comment: You also mentioned that you ran as a spring project , I am assuming that you used STS . Just run your jar using java -jar {yourjarpath} along with any relavent spring profiles if required > i.e., 
(-Dspring.profiles.active=dev}